# Github: view content of two separate branches merged into one target branch?

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch called `target`, and inside this branch I merged branch `a`, with:

```
git merge a
```

(from within `target` branch)

And also merged branch `b`, with:

```
 git merge b
```

(also from within the `target` branch)

Now in branch `target` I have the content of the two branches, a and b.
I push branch `target` to Github.

Is there a way to show in Github the content of branch a, and branch b, separately?

Comment: GitHub will happily show you any branch that it knows about.  But: "Now in branch main I have the content of the two branches, an and b" You do??? When did that happen? According to your account, you merged an and b into target, not main. In fact, from what you've said so far, there is no reason to believe that GitHub has ever heard of a, b, or target.

Comment: Sorry typing mistake, there's no main, only target, a, and b.
Please don't close the question, just a typo, thanks

Comment: As always, "a is a branch" means "a refers to a particular commit (and some metadata)".  If you want to see the content of a, examine the commit.  If you want to see the difference between a and main, examine the diff between the two commits.  Stop thinking of a branch as "a commit and all of its ancestors and all of the human generated ideations that I have placed onto this mystical object".  Think of it as a single commit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for your answer. In order to examine the content of "a", must I also push "a"? When I examine the commits under "target", I cannot see separation between commits from "a" and "b", at least on Github. I only see a list of the commits from both branches.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't be using github to examine your diffs.  If you have the commit locally, there's no need to push it at all.  Either use `git-diff` in a terminal or install gitkraken or use gitk or use some other ui oriented tool locally.   If you don't have any of these tools installed, it might be a good exercise to learn how to install one of them.  (But you certainly do have `git-diff`, and I believe `gitk` still comes by default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to show in Github the content of branch `a`, and branch `b`, separately?

No, for the simple reason that branches `a` and `b` do not exist on GitHub. That's because you never pushed those branches. A branch is a name. Pushing a branch ensures that the remote knows about that name. You never did that, so it doesn't.

But if you

```
git switch a
git push origin a
git switch b
git push origin b
```

Then yes. Choose the branch name from the little pop-up menu at the top left:

[image]

But, as you've been told in a comment, if you concentrate your mind on the *commit that is pointed to by the name `a`* and the *commit that is pointed to by the name `b`*, then yes, *those* have been pushed to GitHub, and GitHub will happily show each of those commits to you, with no need to push the branch names. I very often use that fact when giving instructions to users of my repo: "To see such-and-such a state, look at commit `abcdef1`."

And this is much the better way, because a branch name, once that branch has been merged into another branch, is usually no longer need and should be deleted. You should not perpetuate a branch name merely as a way to look up a commit.

If you need *that* sort of functionality, however, give the commit a *tag* (and push the tag) — that is exactly what tags are for. A tag is a permanent bookmark for finding a commit. Tags are easy to find in GitHub, because
they are in that same pop-up.

Comment: Thank you very much. After pushing both branches, the only way to view their content is by creating a PR for them? My intention was to create one PR from branch "target", that includes two different tasks, one on branch "a" and the other on "b". Plus say a few general changes, and then give the reviewer an option to isolate the tasks and see only changes from a, and b. Is it not possible, except for just viewing "a" and "b" on their own separate PRs?

Comment: "After pushing both branches, the only way to view their content is by creating a PR for them?" No, after pushing both branches as I stated above, GitHub will show either of them to you directly. No need for a PR just to see them.

Comment: I see, interesting, thanks, about your last paragraph, you mean that you would have to find the hash of the commit pointed by the name a, and then view it on Github? Could you please explain how you would do this or attach some link? Thanks again

Comment: You would say, for example, on  your machine, `git rev-parse a`. This tells you the hash of the commit pointed to by `a`. Now go to `https://github.com/<you>/<yourrepo>/commit/<thecommit>`

Comment: But see my additional remark about using a tag rather than a branch if you wish to bookmark a commit permanently.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the compare screen to compare two branches (I've used the bun repo as a random example):
https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/compare
Comparing two branches, "1-runner" into "main":
https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/compare/main...1-runner

You can't pull apart two branches from a merge, since the point is that they're merged and there might have been conflicts that you resolved which means they are no longer either of the original branches, but a combination of them. You can however compare the individual source branches to see what changes they make to your final merge branch.